# Kalman Filter Forecasting converging?

Tags: forecasting, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I have implemented Kalman Filter to forecast 250 forward steps of some observations

The formula I used after recursively filtering on the in-sample set is

$y_{T+h|T} = HB^hz_{T|T}$

where H and B are the system matrices as described here http://homepage.univie.ac.at/robert.kunst/statespace.pdf.

B is 1 in my case.

When apply the above equation the forecast values are converging after some steps to a specific value.

Does this generally makes sense?

Edit: My guess would be that it makes sense as there a no measurements to update the forecast as it happens in the 'in-sample filtering'